# VBA: Why will Autofilter not work when manual filter does? (Run-time error '1004': Method 'AutoFilter' of object 'Range' failed)

Tags: vba, excel

Getting a Run time error for the following code.

Working with a data dump that has data in rows 1000, etc for some columns. From what I read on other forums, autofilter won't work if there is no values "near" the cell. However, when I put in test value closer to the filter, it still won't work. Manual filter is working on this same range.

```
CURrow = ActiveCell.Row
LASTrow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
LASTcol = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
If LASTrow > CURrow Then
    Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range(Cells(CURrow + 1, 1), Cells(LASTrow, 1)).Value = "|"
    Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(Cells(CURrow, 1), Cells(CURrow, LASTcol - 1)).AutoFilter
    Rows(CURrow + 1).Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If
```

Comment: Just wondering, if you add something like this to the top of your code, would it work? `Worksheets("NAME").Select` ? Instead of "NAME" write the name of the worksheet.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but still didn't work. Thanks for the thought though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to do and how it does not work.

Your code

- adds a column to the left
- types a pipe to all the rows below the    selected cell (row)
- puts on the filter function **starting from the    selected row** and
  including not the two rightmost columns (the added    and -1 makes
  -2) of the original data
- uses Freeze Pane to keep the    selected row visible while scrolling

IF your idea were to filter out the rows you marked with pipes, you'd need a title for the column AND IF the column titles would be on row 1 my modified version would be like this:

```
Sub MarkForFilterFromHereBelow()

CURrow = ActiveCell.Row
LASTrow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
LASTcol = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column

If LASTrow > CURrow Then
Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range(Cells(CURrow + 1, 1), Cells(LASTrow, 1)).Value = "|"
Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(1, 1).Value = "FilterColumn" 'This is the column title
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LASTrow, LASTcol + 1)).AutoFilter
'Here you can add a row to filter the rows marked with |?
Rows(2).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If

End Sub
```

But clearly I have too many ifs to answer to your question. :-)